# Rules of powers of exponents

Tags: exponential-function

Why is $e^x \times e^{\ln 2} = e^{x \times \ln 2}$ Not correct?

I thought that if you had something to the power, you could split them
E.g $e^4 = e^2.e^2$

Sorry for the lack of latex I find it very confusing to use.

Comment: Well, the issue you have is that $4=2 \times 2=2+2$... So in fact $e^x \times e^y=e^{x+y}$.

Comment: $e^4=(e^2)(e^2)$ is valid not because $e^4=e^{(2)(2)}$but$=e^{2+2}$

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks makes sense.

Comment: More ever $e^{\ln 2}= 2$ hence your statement is $2 e^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^n\cdot b^m = a^{n+m}$. Same follows for exponent.